# Symfony2 - JSMSerializerBundle ISO8601 - request not valid

Tags: symfony, iso8601

My page sends a ajax request with payload:

```
start_date: "2014-07-03T21:37:01.396Z"
```

The date has been created with:

```
 var start_date = new Date();
```

I've tried in the same way:

```
 var start_date = new Date().toISOstring;
```

The JMSSerializer needs this dateformat: Y-m-d\TH:i:sO. But is complaining:

```
"Invalid datetime \"2014-07-03T21:37:01.396Z\", expected format Y-m-d\\TH:i:sO."
```

My Entity-field has a annotation:

```
 @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
```

Type datetime comes from MySql DateTime.

Comment: I am having the same issue. From what I have read so far .396Z is the timezone offset in JS (396 minutes?). PHP is looking for the offset in the following format +HH:MM or +HHMM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. I ended up using moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

```
 var start_date = new Date();
 start_date = moment(start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ssZZ');
```

Comment: I found this post which gives an alternative solution by changing the expected format inside symfony: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160808/getting-missmatch-in-datetime-format-using-jms-serializer-and-iso8601