# Getting missmatch in datetime format using jms serializer and ISO8601

Tags: symfony, doctrine, iso8601, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am getting this message:

```
Invalid datetime "2017-11-07T19:46:57.118Z", expected format Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP.
```

When using JMS Serializer and the config:

```
jms_serializer:
    handlers:
        datetime:
            default_format: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'
```

I think that my supplied date is in the correct format, but apparently not. Is it something that is wrong with the date?

Comment: The date doc say one slash. Have you try it? `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'`

Comment: Yes, with the same result

Comment: The format problem seems to be from `.118` . it seems to be microsecond

Comment: Have you tried with `default_format: "c"` ?

Comment: I tried c, but that did not solve it. About the microseconds, is that in the ISO8601 or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a tough one, I've run into it before. I was using annotations so my fix looked like:

```
 @Serializer\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT'>")
```

So I'm guessing yours is going to look like:

```
jms_serializer:
    handlers:
        datetime:
            default_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT'
```

Or you may have to add another slash in there before "TH" if jms reads yaml files differently than annotations.

Can't remember exactly why this happens, I just remember trying a hundred different combinations until one worked. At any rate, dates and times are hard.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. Yeah, this is a tough one. That error message is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
jms_serializer:
handlers:
    datetime:
        default_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP'
```

Use 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP' if you want to serialize/deserialize joda DateTime

(using joda DateTimeConverter on the client)